# Cakephp: Redirecting to particular div in the view.

Tags: cakephp, redirect, hyperlink, render, helper

My navigation is in the header of default layout. I am trying to set up one of the navigation button to redirect to particular div () on the home page. 
I have this, which does not work:

```
<li> <?php
echo $this->Html->link(
'ABOUT',
array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'display','home'),
array('id' => 'about_page'),
array('escape' => FALSE)); ?> </li>
```

this page controller just takes argument and redirects to the certain page. it looks like this:

```
public function display() {
    $path = func_get_args();
            $page = $path[0];


                $count = count($path);
                if (!$count) {
                        return $this->redirect('/');
                }
                $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

                if (!empty($path[0])) {
                        $page = $path[0];
                }
                if (!empty($path[1])) {
                        $subpage = $path[1];
                }
                if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
                        $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
                }
                $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));

                try {
                        $this->render(implode('/', $path));
                } catch (MissingViewException $e) {
                        if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                                throw $e;
                        }
                        throw new NotFoundException();
                }

}
```

Can someone please help me? may be there is an easier to redirect with render or redirect method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correct the only thing you need to do is

```
<li> <?php
echo $this->Html->link(
'ABOUT',
array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'display','home', '#' => 'about_page'),
array('escape' => FALSE)); ?> </li>
```

you just need to add the '#' to your array and not id.

**Edit**

```
<li> <?php
echo $this->Html->link(
'ABOUT',
array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'display','home', '#' => 'about_page', 'escape' => FALSE)); ?> </li>
```

The fourth parameter is the confirmMessage and not the escape option that i wrote above.

Comment: for some reason the little dialog box shows up saying "The pages at local host says: object Object" and then it redirects me to home page, but does not take to 'about_page' div.

Comment: It is getting better, It does not show a message box, but still it just redirects to home page, but not to about_page div

Comment: if the out put of the above command is `http://myapp/pages/display/home#about_page` then the problem must be in your html at the home page.